# Having trouble building ios solutions. The remote macOs agent & VS 2017

Tags: xcode, cordova

Good afternoon. I'm having trouble building ios solutions.

I'm using VS 2017. The remote macOs agent is configured on a virtual machine. MacOs latest version, Xcode too

Having started the assembly, I've been getting only information about the state of the assembly for four hours already. And nothing more is happening. Tell me please, is this normal?

I'll attach a piece of code from the VS console.

```
------ 05/14/2018 14:51:23 The build status is checked из http://192.168.44.130:3000/cordova/build/tasks/571 [Try 2213]

------ Information about the new build: {"command":"build","vcordova":"6.3.1","cfg":"release","options":"--device","status":"Building","buildCommand":"build","buildPlatform":"ios","configuration":"release","buildDir":"/Users/bogdan/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/571","buildNumber":571,"logLevel":0,"submissionTime":"2018-05-14T08:45:46.408Z","changeList":{"deletedFiles":[]},"buildSuccessful":false,"messageId":"AcquiringCordova","messageArgs":[null],"message":"Acquiring Cordova.","tgzFilePath":"/Users/bogdan/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/571/upload_571.tgz","appDir":"/Users/bogdan/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/571/cordovaApp","statusTime":"2018-05-14T08:45:50.119Z","appName":"diaservice"}
```

Building - Acquiring Cordova.

Comment: What can you see in the console window where you are running remotebuild? Also have you checked the build log? (should be in .taco-home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/571)

Comment: Kind time of the day, thank you for attention to my problem.

In the console on a MacOS machine, only GET requests for this path are .taco-home / remote-builds / taco-remote / builds / 123, all with a 200 response

Yes, I checked the logs, there only information about the fact that the assembly is running, on this all

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Visual Studio will fail in 90% of the cases when trying to compile the iOS app, specially when using plugins like the push plugin. The only way I found to compile it properly was to open the project in xCode (the one copied by Visual Studio when it tries to compile) and then compile or deploy from xCode itself.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Could you more like tell about this

I'm doing a project in VS, using the apache cordova tools, that is, using js / html / css. Is it possible in this case to deceive the fate and at some stage to shift everything onto the shoulders of XCode?

Comment: To manage the iOS app exclusively from xCode, I would create a new project following the exact [steps from the Cordova guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/), then import my **www** folder, overwriting the default one. And of course, install plugins and platforms from the CLI as xCode does not understand anything about Cordova apps. However, now you have to manage the Android and iOS apps separately, which is twice the work. But compiling the iOS version from VS could be worse than that, of course.

Comment: Good afternoon, thank you very much, I do not understand everything, because I know very little about xcode itself. But I'll try to sort this out today. If you do not mind, I'll contact you here, a little later, if I have any questions in the cour se of work